# MySQL: Group by query optimization

Tags: mysql, group-by, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group, groupwise-maximum

I've got a table of the following schema:

```
+----+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| id | amount | created_timestamp          | updated_timestamp          |
+----+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| 1  |   1.00 | 2018-01-09 12:42:38.973222 | 2018-01-09 12:42:38.973222 |
+----+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Here, for `id = 1`, there could be multiple amount entries. I want to extract the last added entry and its corresponding amount, grouped by id.

I've written a working query with an inner join on the self table as below:

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       t1.amount, 
       t1.created_timestamp, 
       t1.updated_timestamp 
FROM   transactions AS t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT id, 
                          Max(updated_timestamp) AS last_transaction_time 
                   FROM   transactions 
                   GROUP  BY id) AS latest_transactions 
               ON latest_transactions.id = t1.id 
                  AND latest_transactions.last_transaction_time = 
                      t1.updated_timestamp;
```

I think inner join is an overkill and this can be replaced with a more optimized/efficient query. I've written the following query with `where`, `group by`, and `having` but it isn't working. Can anyone help?

```
select id, any_value(`updated_timestamp`), any_value(amount) from transactions group by `id` having max(`updated_timestamp`);
```

Comment: This is how you do it in MySQL:

Comment: You mean with the inner join and that is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Yes, in MySQL I see no better way to do it.

Comment: Do you have an index on `(id,updated_timestamp)`? And what's your PRIMARY KEY (assuming it's not `(id,updated_timestamp)`)

Comment: So, there is no primary key. But there are individual indexes on `id` & `updated_timestamp `

Answer (score 2):

There are two (good) options when performing a query like this in MySQL. You have already tried one option. Here is the other:

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       t1.amount, 
       t1.created_timestamp, 
       t1.updated_timestamp 
FROM   transactions AS t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions later_transactions
       ON later_transactions.id = t1.id 
       AND later_transactions.last_transaction_time > t1.updated_timestamp
WHERE  later_transactions.id IS NULL
```

These methods are the ones in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html), and also the ones I use in my work basically every day. Which one is most efficient depends on a variety of factors, but usually, if one is slow the other will be fast.

Also, as Strawberry points out in the comments, you need a composite index on `(id,updated_timestamp)`. Have separate indexes for `id` and `updated_timestamp` is not equivalent.

## Why a composite index?

Be aware that an index is just a copy of the data that is in the table. In many respects, it works the same as a table does. So, creating an index is creating a copy of the table's data that the RDBMS can use to query the table's information in a more efficient manner.

An index on just `updated_timestamp` will create a copy of the data that contains `updated_timestamp` as the first column, and that data will be sorted. It will also include a hidden row ID value (that will work as a primary key) in each of those index rows, so that it can use that to look up the full rows in the actual table.

How does that help in this query (either version)? If we wanted just the latest (or earliest) `updated_timestamp` overall, it would help, since it can just check the first or last record in the index. But since we want the latest for each `id`, this index is useless.

What about just an index on `id`. Here we have a copy of the `id` column, sorted by the `id` column, with the row ID attached to each row in the index.

How does this help this query? It doesn't, because it doesn't even have the `updated_timestamp` column as part of the index, and so won't even consider using this index.

Now, consider a composite index: `(id,updated_timestamp)`.

This creates a copy of the data with the `id` column first, sorted, and then the second column `updated_timestamp` is also included, and it is also sorted within each `id`.

This is the same way that a phone book (if people still use those things as something more than paperweights) is sorted by last name and then first name.

Because the rows are sorted in this way, MySQL can look, for each `id`, at just the last record of a given `id`. It knows that that record contains the highest `updated_timestamp` value, because of how the index is defined.

So, it only has to look up one row for each `id` that exists. That is fast. Further explanation into why would take up a lot more space, but you can research it yourself if you like, by just looking into B-Trees. Suffice to say, finding the first (or last) record is easy.

Try the following:

```
ALTER TABLE transactions
ADD INDEX `LatestTransaction` (`id`,`updated_timestamp`)
```

And then see whether your original query or my alternate query is faster. Likely both will be faster than having no index. As your table grows, or your select statement changes it may affect which of these queries is faster, but the index is going to provide the biggest performance boost, regardless of which version of the query you use.

Comment: I didn't understand why having a composite index on `(id,updated_timestamp)` is better than individual indexes. Please explain that.

Comment: @PankajSinghal I have added an explanation on why a composite index is required.

Comment: That looks like an Order(N*N) algorithm.  There are Order(N) methods.  Even faster: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Comment: @RickJames Please leave an answer yourself if you have another solution. The core issue for this question appears to be the lack of appropriate index. After adding that, his original query likely will perform quite fast.